# scheme' conditional expression and evaluation order

Tags: scheme, racket

thinking following expression:

```
(cond (p1 (some_complex_expression1))
      (p2 (some_complex_expression2))
      (p3 (some_complex_expression3))
      ...
      (else (some_complex_expressionN)))
```

are those `(some_complex_expressionX)`s evaluated on demand? (i.e. '(some_complex_expressionX)' is only evaluated when the predicate before itself, `pX` is true) or, do they follow applicative order(they are somehow evaluated as much as possible before trying predicates)

if that is implementation-dependent, how about those following implementations?

```
mit-scheme
guile
racket
that scheme for sicp
r5rs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The test must return a true value before the associated expressions are evaluated. This is guaranteed by the Scheme standards; see [section 4.2.1 of R5RS](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.2.1), for example.

Answer (score 1):

For the gory details on Racket, see the [Reference Manual](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/).  For this question, you're asking about the semantics of [`cond`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/if.html#%28form._%28%28lib._racket/private/letstx-scheme..rkt%29._cond%29%29); the documentation there steps through the details on what is or isn't evaluated under what conditions.